# Responsive React App via CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Right now, my app looks almost exactly how I want it too via larger screens. https://imgur.com/a/MCe5D - As you shrink the screen size down, the two columns (trending up and trending down) will get closer and closer until they are just about touching, which is great. But at that instance when they no longer get any closer, I would like to have the Trending Down and it's contents move underneath the Trending Up column, to be more mobile friendly. [Here's a pen showing the area that is being affected.](https://codepen.io/scottmiller2/pen/KyqWzw)

```
//The whole area surrounding the two columns
.playersColumns {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-evenly;
padding-left: 150px;
padding-right: 150px;
padding-top: 25px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

//The two columns of player info
.playersBody {
overflow: auto;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
min-width: 255px;
}
```

That pen isn't very useful, but it shows my exact code and which tags are where. I tried putting the 2nd column of player info and trend header inside of the first one, but that just made it one large column (which is what I want, but only when the screen is shrunk)

Any help is appreciated — if there is a better way to display the code or layout, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking into Media Queries.
[Here](https://youtu.be/2KL-z9A56SQ) is a short video to show you the basics.

You can set a threshold that will trigger separate styles under those conditions. It can be very useful when you want your UI to do something different at different sizes.

```
@media only screen 
and (*Your threshold criteria goes here* EXAMPLE:  max-width : 1000px) {   
  //css goes here with whatever css you want to fire at this threshold
}
```